# How to write VLOOKUP formula correctly in Excel VBA? What is the error?

Tags: vba, vlookup

I want 'vlookup' formula in Range("H1:H70")

```
For i = 1 To 70
    Worksheets(1).Range("H"&i).Formula= "=VLOOKUP("F"&i;'anotherSheet'!$A:$C;2;0)"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct spelling is `Sheets(1).Range("H" & i).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(F" & i & ",'anotherSheet'!$A:$C,2,0)"`

Depending on your language settings you use `;` as a separator when you type formulas in a worksheet, but you use `,` when typing formulas in VBA.